# Why am I getting what seems to be some kind of redraw lag with this PyQt5 movable QGraphicsItem, and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview

When I run this code on my computer, it works fine for the most part. But if I click and drag the circle around too quickly, whichever side is "forward" in terms of the movement will get occluded by the background color. If I drag very fast, I get discrete, white afterimages of the object (even though the object is red). I  I'm guessing that whatever code is updating the canvas is taking too long to get there with the first one; I don't really know about the afterimages.

It's hard to describe, so I recommend you look at this [screencast of the behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2b4KO.jpg)

The code is below. Is there a way to fix this?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QGraphicsEllipseItem, QGraphicsRectItem, QGraphicsItem
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

scene = QGraphicsScene(0,0,600,400)

rect = QGraphicsRectItem(50,20,200,50)
circle = QGraphicsEllipseItem(75,30,100,100)

# this is how you change fill and outline color
brush = QBrush(Qt.red)
pen = QPen(Qt.black)
pen.setWidth(2)

circle.setBrush(brush)
circle.setPen(pen)
rect.setBrush(brush)
rect.setPen(pen)

# stacking order is maintained; use setZValue to shuffle
scene.addItem(circle)
scene.addItem(rect)

scene.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt.cyan))

# we can set the item to be moveable AFTER it's added to the scene
circle.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
rect.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)

view = QGraphicsView(scene)
view.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: I don't see any "white afterimage" in that video.

Comment: I've done another test with frame-by-frame checking, and I can confirm that I see no "white afterimage" in the video, as the objects properly follow the mouse as expected. Maybe some refresh issue on your video driver or screen? Can you do a frame-by-frame test on your own, using the video you posted?